# Null spaces getting added to decrypted D01 file while using AES-256/CBC/PKCS7PADDING

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption, aes, pkcs#7

I am using AES-256/CBC/PKCS7PADDING for encrypting a d01 file. After encrypting the file I am performing decrypting the same file for my testing but While decrypting the file extra null values are getting added to the do1 file. I am using bouncycastle library here.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.BufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.CipherParameters;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.engines.AESFastEngine;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.modes.CBCBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.BlockCipherPadding;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.KeyParameter;
import org.bouncycastle.crypto.params.ParametersWithIV;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class CryptoUtilsV2 {

   public static byte[] iv = generateIV();
  public int encryptDCRenewal(String keyText, File inputFile, File outputFile)
      throws Exception {
    //inputFile is d01 file and outfile is the d01 file to which encrypted data is written
   // initialize key and iv
    byte[] secretKey = keyText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
    inputStream.read(inputBytes);
    inputStream.close();
    // Encrypt the message
    byte[] ciphertext = encrypt(inputBytes, secretKey, iv);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    outputStream.write(ciphertext);
    outputStream.close();
    return 0;
  }

  public int decryptDCRenewal(String keyText, File inputFile, File outputFile)
      throws Exception {
    // initialize key and iv
    //inputFile is encrypted d01 file and outfile is the do1 file to which decrypted data is written
    byte[] secretKey = keyText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    byte[] inputBytes = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
    inputStream.read(inputBytes);
    inputStream.close();
    // Encrypt the message
    byte[] decryptedText = decrypt(inputBytes, secretKey, iv);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
    outputStream.write(decryptedText);
    outputStream.close();
    return 0;
  }

  private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] ciphertext, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception {
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = createCipher(false, key, iv);
    byte[] output = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(ciphertext.length)];
    int bytesWritten = cipher.processBytes(ciphertext, 0, ciphertext.length, output, 0);
    bytesWritten += cipher.doFinal(output, bytesWritten);
    return output;
  }
  private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] iv) throws Exception {
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = createCipher(true, key, iv);
    byte[] output = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
    int bytesWritten = cipher.processBytes(input, 0, input.length, output, 0);
    bytesWritten += cipher.doFinal(output, bytesWritten);
    return output;
  }

  private static BufferedBlockCipher createCipher(boolean forEncryption, byte[] key, byte[] iv) {
    BlockCipherPadding padding = new PKCS7Padding();
    BufferedBlockCipher cipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(
        new CBCBlockCipher(new AESEngine()), padding);
    CipherParameters params = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv);
    cipher.init(forEncryption, params);
    return cipher;
  }
  private static byte[] generateIV() {
    byte[] iv = new byte[16]; // AES 256 use 16 byte IV
    new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);
    return iv;
  }
}
```

the key value is : Qxyyywqg1UdBRpUV

original d01 file content

[image]

the decrypted d01 file content:

[image]

Comment: Are you aware of the Cipher input and output streams?

Comment: Two things: a. use `org.bouncycastle.crypto.io.CipherInputStream;` (and equiv. output) b. post the input file as text *formatted as code*

Comment: As alluded to by @user207421, you are welcome to use the BouncyCastle API but, as far as I can see, there is no advantage to using it in your code sample. By using Java builti-in cryptography, CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream, and the File.copy() methods you can reduce all this jumble of code to just a few lines.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk Cipher stream classes come with the JRE. I didn’t say anything about BouncyCastle and I don’t see any reason to use it here.

Answer (score 0):

`getOutputSize(..)` don't return what you expect:

> `int getOutputSize(int len)`
> return the size of the output buffer required for an update plus a doFinal with an input of len bytes.

The method is used for calculate how big a message will be when encrypted .. not for decryption.

You can only see the size of the decrypted message after the padding have been removed, which happens during decryption. You actually calculate the size of the decrypted message in `bytesWritten` and then ignores the result.

Comment: so what are you suggesting me to do here?

Comment: Well, you should use the information (number of bytes) returned to you by processBytes(..)  and doFinal(..), so you know how much of your buffer have been filled. Now you just assume your buffer is filled up - but it ain't.

Comment: I tried to use that information but it ain't working for me ...that's why I wanted help ...may be my problem here is how to use that information properly

Comment: @TJ32 - `getOutputSize()` generally returns a buffer that is too large (due to padding). The *actual* size of the plaintext that you store in `bytesWritten` is only determined during decryption. You just need to shorten the buffer, e.g. with `return Arrays.copyOf(output, bytesWritten);`